# How to extract Dynamic text from a webpage

Tags: java, web-services

I want to get some text from webpage those are frequently changed.What are the technologies I cab use for this?,AS an example Currency rate that change everyday I want to extract from web page and want to save in DB,pls let me know any one knows about this,

thanxx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML.

Example :

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

You can look for particular DIV , tag this way, Check [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)